# Muuri Receive event not triggered

Tags: javascript, muuri

So I'm trying to create nestable element using Muuri

I've based my code on this example https://codepen.io/Hyzau/pen/rNmpowd
This is an edited version of Niklas Rämö's code with some `console.log()` added for comparison's sake.

In this code, you can see the `receive` and `send` event triggered when you move a red box from the left to the right. If you release the box, the `dragReleaseStart` is triggered.

Now I changed it quite a bit in order to fit my own needs.
You can see my codepen here : https://codepen.io/Hyzau/pen/gOWoZmb
In my code `receive` and `send` event are never triggered and I'm not sure why.

For each subgrid as well as the main grid, I have the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i < subgridDom.length; i++)
{
    opt.items = getChildrenByClass(subgridDom[i], 'item');
    subgrid[i] = new Muuri(subgridDom[i], opt);
    subgrid[i].on('receive', muuriReceive);
    subgrid[i].on('send', muuriSend);
    subgrid[i].on('dragReleaseStart', muuriDragStart);
}
```

This code should enable the `receive` and `send` event, but it doesn't seems to work. The `dragReleaseStart` however, works properly. Can someone explain me why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The dragSort Option should be either true or a function returning an array of all grids used to move as is said in the documentation :

> Alternatively you can do some advanced stuff and control within which grids a specific item can be sorted and dragged into. To do that you need to provide a function which receives the dragged item as its first argument and should return an array of grid instances. **An important thing to note here is that you need to return all the grid instances you want the dragged item to sort within, even the current grid instance.** If you return an empty array the dragged item will not cause sorting at all.

https://github.com/haltu/muuri#grid-option-dragsort

Here is what have changed in the code :

```
var opt = {
    dragSort: muuriGetAllGrids, // you need to call a function that returns all grid
};

function muuriGetAllGrids(item)
{
    return subgrid; // Should return an array of all the grid in which an item can be sorted
}

// [...]

subgrid.push(grid1); // After initialization, add the main grid to the array of subgrid
```